# Disabling file caching for c++ code

Tags: c++, caching

I wonder if there is a way to disable file caching for c++ code. I am running some tests in reading, writing and modifying certain file formats from disk, and the timing tests are skewed most possibly due to caching. I was wondering if there is any quick way to turn off caching using any compiler directives or OS-specific commands?

My tests are currently built using gmake on linux, mac and windows. Any suggestions/comments are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On POSIX compliant OS, [fsync](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync) might be what you're looking for. Call it before you read a file and after you modify. This will probably slow down your program a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a platform-independent way of doing this, or a Windows-specific method?

Comment: I find it quite likely that windows api has an equivalent. I don't know of a cross platform wrapper, but writing one yourself shouldn't be too difficult once you figure out the appropriate function.

Answer (score 0):

int setvbuf ( FILE * stream, char * buffer, int mode, size_t size );

with parameter _IONBF No buffer is used. Each I/O operation is written as soon as possible. In this case, the buffer and size parameters are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at `O_DIRECT` option. It (most of the time) asks OS to bypass caching.